# "Additional CSS" Deleting

Tags: css, wordpress

I added some custom CSS styling in the "Additional CSS" tab on my Wordpress site to resize my site's logo image. It worked fine at the time, but now I want to undo that to go back to default. When I delete all my custom CSS from this section, the logo is now smaller than its default size was before I started customizing. There are no other options for logo size in this theme. I tried clearing my host's cache and tried using another browser but none of that solves this tiny logo problem. Is there something else I need to do to get this element back to default settings?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question needs more details. Theme options varies widely depending on the theme.

Comment: It's the Woocommerce Storefront theme. And thanks for the welcome.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your theme? Or how about just adding a new CSS rule to properly size the logo?

Comment: I just tried reinstalling the theme and the logo is still tiny. If I put my custom CSS back in it still works as it did. I am completely new to this. I am worried that adding any custom CSS even in this area can permanently mess up a theme and wanted to know how to fix it.

I found info saying that storefront recommends a logo 470px x 110px. Mine is shown at 230px x 36px despite the source image being 628px x 98px

Comment: Here is my site. I don't have much there as I am just trying to learn. https://laserpatternshop.com/

Comment: According to [this commit](https://github.com/woocommerce/storefront/commit/30d4977d728036aeffe8e88ab6bf9e5b3c8545a1), the max width of logo got changed to 230px from 100% since v2.3.0. The theme got updated so 230px is the latest default settings. From looking at your site, you're using v2.5.5.

Comment: OK, well thank you very much for digging that up. I swear it was bigger than that at first. Maybe my brain was getting mushy after messing with this all day. That would explain why it stayed after reinstalling. I was worried I had permanently changed something.

Answer (score 0):

for most of themes, the logo size is adjustable at theme's option panel, try to find that option first.

Secondly, adding css directly to "additional css" is not a right way to modify wordpress site. All you need to do is adding your custom css code in your child theme.

To debug, you can check the theme demo site and inspect its logo css and match your ones and compare if having any differences, could be other plugins having the same class name which override your theme's one. Then you need to add custom css code (make it important if have to) in your child theme css file to override it.

Hope it helps, thanks